# Carrierwave empty files - The file “MyDocument.pdf” could not be opened because it is empty

Tags: carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave to upload files. On my development machine running OS X 10.8 I am able to upload the file and download the file as expected. Tailing the development log I see:

```
Started GET "/resources/download_file/11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-24 06:29:33 -0400
Processing by ResourcesController#download_file as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
  Resource Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "resources".* FROM "resources" WHERE "resources"."id" = ?     LIMIT 1  [["id", "11"]]
Sent file     /Users/scervera/rails_apps/mdn/public/uploads/resource/document/11/MyDocument.pdf (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

After deploying with Capistrano onto my Ubuntu 12.04 server VM, I am able to upload the file (and verify it is physically on the server), however, when I click on the link to download the file I receive a message that says:

"The file “MyDocument.pdf” could not be opened because it is empty."

Tailing the production.log shows this:

```
Started GET "/resources/download_file/1" for 192.168.0.90 at 2013-03-24 06:31:12 -0400
Processing by ResourcesController#download_file as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Sent file     /var/mdnapp/releases/20130322184251/public/uploads/resource/document/1/MyDocument.pdf (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Note that this sql line is missing:

```
Resource Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "resources".* FROM "resources" WHERE "resources"."id" = ?
```

When I tried to open the file, it is indeed empty.

Also, I have tried adding the following to my deploy.rb, but while this is helpful, did not solve this particular problem:

```
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/uploads}
```

**Additional Details**
I have a resources_controller with a method called download_file. See below:

```
def download_file
  @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
  send_file(@resource.document.path,
        :type => 'application/pdf',
        :disposition => 'attachment',
        :url_based_filename => true)
end
```

In my view I have a link tag that calls this method. See view code below:

```
<% if @resources.empty? %>
    <p>There are no resources available at this time.</p>

<% else %>
    <% @resources.each do |resource| %>

    <div class="resource_wrap clearfix">
            <h1><%= resource.title.html_safe %></h1><h2><%= resource.subtitle.html_safe %></h2>
        <p><%= image_tag resource.image_url(:wallet).to_s %><%= resource.description.html_safe %></p>

        <div id="attachments">
            <% if resource.document? %>
                <p>Get the resource:<%= link_to 'Download File', :action => 'download_file', :id => resource.id %></p>
            <% end %>
            <% if resource.video? %>
                <p>Get the video:<%= link_to 'Download Video', :action => 'download_video', :id => resource.id %></p>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm running rails 3.2.11, ruby 1.9.3p194, carrierwave 0.8.0, rmagick 2.13.2

Please let me know if you need any additional details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I figured out the problem. I had to edit my config/environments/production.rb file and commented out the following line:

config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"

Spent a lot of hours researching this one. I hope someone else can benefit.

Comment: Same problem here, thanks! I was using Nginx but for some reason was still using the `"X-sendfile"` which I think is for Apache. I set mine to `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx` as it should have been, and it works fine.